# Moving Ros folder

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to change the ROS folder location.
The current directory is: root/opt/ros
but if I just move it (cut, paste), ROS it doesn't work
How can I move it to my desktop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48256/moving-ros-folder/) by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-14**:
Why would you like it to be placed on your desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually you would keep the system folder for ROS there and add another folder to your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable. I usually like to use `~/ros` for my packages or packages I downloaded from other people's repositories.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, I think it's a pretty bad idea to move ros packages that were installed by debian packages (everything in `/opt/ros/`). Setting ROS_PACKAGE_PATH will not be enough because the binaries and libraries in ros packages contain RPATH information to not require LD_LIRBARY_PATH set. When you move the packages, the rpaths will become incorrect and you won't be able to run any nodes anymore. A second problem is that every update will re-install ros packages at the old location.

The only thing you can do is creating a symbolic link. You can move /opt/ros and then create the link with:

```
ln -s /opt/ros <new location of ros>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-14**:
You'd want: ln -s /opt/ros

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-14**:
Damn. Right. Edited my post. Thanks!